# Deep Links not working with Capacitor, Ionic 7 on native and PWA? (redirecting Stripe Payments from the Firebase Stripe Extension)

Tags: stripe-payments, deep-linking, capacitor, ionic7

Deep Linking doesn't seem to be working using Ionic 7 and Capacitor.

app.component.ts:

```
import { Component, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { App, URLOpenListenerEvent } from '@capacitor/app';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['app.component.scss'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private router: Router, private zone: NgZone) {
    this.initializeApp();
}

initializeApp() {
  App.addListener('appUrlOpen', (event: URLOpenListenerEvent) => {
      this.zone.run(() => {
        
          const slug = event.url.split("<domain>").pop();
          if (slug) {
              this.router.navigateByUrl(slug);
          }
          // If no match, do nothing - let regular routing
          // logic take over
      });
  });
}

}
```

I'v also deployed the `apple-app-site-association` and `applinks.json` files to , which is also the subdomain the app will reside. I have confirmed that these files are installed and detected in the `.well-known` folder of the site.

In XCode I've added the `Associated Domains` as `applinks:<domain>` and have enabled `Associated Domains` in my Identifiers section on my apple developer profile.

When I go to `<domain>` from either Chrome or Safari in the Sim or my native ios device, the website resolves and doesn't open the application as expected. (I have not tested the deep linking on an Android device as of yet - I've been focusing on iOS first - hoping it would translate - however, I have made the recommended changes to the manifest files and, as mentioned before, I am hosing the json file on my site.)

The reason I wanted to get this working is because I am using the `Firebase Stripe Extension` that requires a `success_url` and `cancel_url` in its implementation to redirect the user back to the app. As you might expect, this works well on the Ionic PWA site, but not natively. I was hoping that deep linking would be the solution to avoid a more manual install and implementation of Stripe.

The Stripe documentation for the firebase extension recommends using the `window.location.origin` as both the success and cancel urls. `window.location.origin` translates to `capacitor://localhost` natively, and stripe errors saying this is an invalid url. I then tried to use the deep link of `<domain>` as the redirect url in both cases, which is accepted by Stripe as a valid url, but the user is redirected to the default browser and linked to the PWA deployment.

My ask is if it is possible to get some sort of universal link to the site as a redirect url that will work both natively and for the PWA deployment? could I implement a switch/case that would detect the platform and substitute the correct redirect.